# SSH to Ubuntu Permission Denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, permissions, openssh

I freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04.04 on a laptop and performed all necessary steps to enable SSH on it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

I am fully aware and verified the IP, username and password on this Ubuntu laptop. I have also disabled firewall on this machine.

But when I attempt to ssh to this machine I get following error:

```
[myusername@mycomputername ~]$ ssh ubuntuname@ubuntuip
ubuntuname@ubuntuip's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
ubuntuname@ubuntuip's password:
```

After looking at multiple forums and websites it was identified to make sure following settings are enabled on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on my ubuntu machine.

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

I have also enabled permissions on:

```
chmod 0700 /home/ubuntuname
chmod 0700 /home/ubuntuname/.ssh
chmod 0600 /home/ubuntuname/.ssh/authorized_keys (created this file)
```

Based from Nasir's comment below also added `AllowUsers myusername@mycomputername`  on my `ubuntuname` machine's `sshd_config` file.

And finally;

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

I have confirmed that I can login directly (i.e. without `ssh`) to the `ubuntuip` server as `ubuntuname`. The UID for `ubuntuname` is `1000`.

```
ubuntuname@ubuntuname:~$ journalctl -g sshd
Mar 22 17:38:12 ubuntuname systemd[1]: ssh.service: Found left-over process 8916 (sshd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Mar 22 17:38:25 ubuntuname sshd[14878]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown.
Mar 22 17:38:25 ubuntuname sshd[14878]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<remote_host_IP>
Mar 24 11:03:50 ubuntuname sshd[17659]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown.
Mar 24 11:03:50 ubuntuname sshd[17659]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<remote_host_IP>
Mar 24 11:47:09 ubuntuname sudo[17750]: ubuntuname : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ubuntuname ; USER=root ;  COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Mar 24 11:47:50 ubuntuname sudo[17754]: ubuntuname : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ubuntuname ; USER=root ;  COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl restart sshd
Mar 24 11:48:16 ubuntuname sshd[17760]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown.
Mar 24 11:48:16 ubuntuname sshd[17760]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<remote_host_IP>
```

Nothing seems to work so far to login to my ubuntu machine. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the user allowed in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file?

Comment: Any useful messages in `/var/log/auth.log`?

Comment: @Nasir how do you allow user in the sshd_config file?

Comment: Add the line `AllowUsers username` to the file and restart the service. Did you research this via Google beforehand? This is one of the first things that you'll find.

Comment: After adding ```AllowUsers mycomputer@username```  on my ```ubuntuname``` machine's ```sshd_config``` file and restarting the service did not help in this case

Comment: It's not `AllowUsers mycomputer@username`. It's `AllowUsers username`. For example, if the username with which you are connecting is `ubuntuname`, then the line should read `AllowUsers ubuntuname`. Afterwards, restart the service.

Comment: Look for sshd in the journal with 'journalctl -g sshd' on the host 'ubuntuip'. The error messages there should indicate what is going wrong.

Comment: @Kapil I see ```check pass; user unknown``` and then ```authentication failure``` with ```rhost``` IP address of the machine I am trying to SSH from

Comment: @roaima 1. Yes I can login with the ```ubuntuname``` without SSH 2. I also tried to SSH to ```root@ubuntuip``` but that does not help either 3. I see UID for the ```ubuntuname``` as ```1000``` not ```0```. 4. Yes

Comment: Remove the `AllowUsers` line. There shouldn't be one of those anywhere in the sshd_config. Likewise comment out `PermitRootLogin yes` as you really should not be allowing this (it doesn't do what you probably think it does). Restart `sshd`

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/696304/edit) to include the full lines from the `journalctl` command you were asked to run. If lines are truncated, repeat the command with `--full`. The full text is important. Obfuscate if you must, but do it consistently and clearly so we can identify `ubuntuname` and the various IP addresses used.

Comment: @roaima updated

Comment: Unless you've copy typed a mistake into the question, `/usr/bin/nano /etc/ssh/sshdconfig` looks wrong - I'm sure even on Ubuntu it should be `sshd_config`

Comment: Here's the issue: `check pass; user unknown`. It suggests you're logging in with the wrong username.

Comment: @roaima you are right. it was modified to match the nomenclature.

Comment: That's strange. There is only one user on this Ubuntu machine. And the names ```myusername``` and ```ubuntuname``` is actually the same. I also tried to do ```ssh root@ubuntuip``` that yield same output as seen here ```Mar 24 12:14:16 ubuntuname sshd[17820]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<remote_host_IP> user root```

Comment: Forget about trying to ssh with a password to root for now. Concentrate on your ordinary user account

Answer (score -1):

you may try this command:

```
sudo passwd username
```

In your case the you should execute below by order:

```
sudo passwd ubuntuname
```

set password for username, then:

```
ssh ubuntuname@ubuntuip
```

Comment: Note that they say they have verified that the username and password are correct and that they can log in directly on the machine.